# Unittesting ZK MVVM ViewModels

Tags: spring, spring-boot, zk

MVVM ViewModels are Pojos, so they are easy to test... At least, that's half the truth. In reality, ViewModels also contain a lot of annotations (`@Command`, `@GlobalCommand`, `@NotifyChanges`). Of course I can test the pojo, but much of the logic is in the annotations, so while 100% of the pojo may be executed, not nearly 100% of the ViewModel will be tested.

Obviously it would be great to test the ViewModel from the Outside, for example by allowing me to do this..

```
MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
BindTestUtil.save(vm, "firstName", "Franklin");
BindTestUtil.verifyNotifyChanged(vm, "someProperty");
```

or...

```
BindTestUtil.doCommand(vm, "someCommand");
...etc.
```

Is there any way to do this? Preferably without having to simulate ZK's code, since that will only lead to guessing what it might do. ZATS is also overkill for a test like this.... Better ideas, anyone?

Comment: I've the same question, my guess is beside Selenium test, you cannot really test a VM.

Comment: @TheBakker I ended up coding something myself, a little wrapper class that simulates ZK Binding behavior via reflection, etc. It's not perfect, but it's a start to test `@NotifyChange`, BindUtils calls, etc. In a unit test, you can then write something like... `VmWrapper wrapper = new VmWrapper(myVm); wrapper.save("property", "xyz"); assertThat(wrapper).wasNotified("property2");` Will put it on Github probably.